# Bug in generated LINQ to SQL class?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables: Budgets and Consultants. There is a 1 to 0..1 relation between Budgets and Consultants: a Budget has a Consultant and a Consultant can have a Budget.

The code generated by Linq to Sql for the Consultant property of a Budget is as follows:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="Consultant_Budget", Storage="_Consultant", ThisKey="Id", OtherKey="Id", IsForeignKey=true, DeleteOnNull=true, DeleteRule="CASCADE")]
public Consultant Consultant
{
    get
    {
        return this._Consultant.Entity;
    }
    set
    {
        Consultant previousValue = this._Consultant.Entity;
        if (((previousValue != value) 
                    || (this._Consultant.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            if ((previousValue != null))
            {
                this._Consultant.Entity = null;
                previousValue.Budget = null;
            }
            this._Consultant.Entity = value;
            if ((value != null))
            {
                value.Budget = this;
                *this._Id = value.Id;*
            }
            else
            {
                *this._Id = default(int);*
            }
            this.SendPropertyChanged("Consultant");
        }
    }
}
```

This seems wrong to me: why does the code change the ID of a Budget (see lines in italic) if its Consultant property is set?

By the way: the tables have been built using Lightswitch.

Comment: Did you experience any errors or idiosyncracies in your code? Or are you just randomly looking at generated code? :)

Comment: I got an error but did not understand what cause it, so I checked the generated code. The error was: An attempt was made to remove a relationship between a Consultant and a Budget. However, one of the relationship's foreign keys (Budget.ID) cannot be set to null.

Comment: seems legit. What does the code look like?

Comment: Let me check my code first: I now have a better understanding of how it works (see Karel Frajtak's answer).

Comment: Found the reason: there was one Consultant with more than one Budget! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Budget depends on the consultant, _Id will contain the ID of the Consultant. When you look into the database, Budget table will contain Id column with primary key constraint and foreign key constraint referencing table for Consultant.

Comment: Ah, thank you Karel. I thought the Budget would have an ID of its own and a Consultant could have this Budget ID in its Budget field, or not.

Comment: It can, but this is (I think) more simple to achieve. Anyway, try to consider the situation when one Consultant can have more Budgets assigned - then you'll need association table and in that case Budget will have its own (identity) primary key.

Comment: Found the reason: there was one Consultant with more than one Budget! Thanks for your help.